# Using a shared_ptr<string> into an unordered_set<string>

Tags: c++, string, shared-ptr, unordered-set

I'm trying to cut down on string copying (which has been measured to be a performance bottleneck in my application) by putting the strings into an `unordered_set<string>` and then passing around `shared_ptr<string>`'s.  It's hard to know when all references to the string in the set have been removed, so I hope that the shared_ptr can help me.  This is the untested code that illustrates how I hope to be able to write it:

```
unordered_set<string> string_pool;
 :
shared_ptr<string> a = &(*string_pool.emplace("foo").first); // .first is an iterator
 :
shared_ptr<string> b = &(*string_pool.emplace("foo").first);
```

In the above, only one instance of the string "foo" should be in string_pool; both a and b should point to it; and at such time that both a and b are destructed, "foo" should be erased from the string_pool.

[The doc on emplace()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/emplace) suggests, but doesn't make clear to me, that pointer `a` can survive a rehashing caused by the allocation of pointer `b`.  It also appears to guarantee that the second emplacement of "foo" will not cause any reallocation, because it is recognized as already present in the set.

Am I on the right track here?  I need to keep the string_pool from growing endlessly, but there's no single point at which I can simply clear() it, nor is there any clear "owner" of the strings therein.

**UPDATE 1**

The history of this problem: this is a "traffic cop" app that reads from servers, parcels out data to other servers, receives their answers, parcels those out to others, receives, and finally assembles and returns a summary answer.  It includes an application protocol stack that receives TCP messages, parses them into string scalar values, which the application then assembles into other TCP messages, sends, receives, etc.  I originally wrote it using `string`s, `vectors<string>`s, and string references, and **valgrind** reported a "high number" of string constructors (even compiled with **-O3**), and high CPU usage that was focused in library routines related to strings.  I was asked to investigate ways to reduce string copying, and designed a "memref" class (**char*** and length pointing into an input buffer) that could be copied around in lieu of the string itself.  Circumstances then arose requiring the input buffer to be reused while memrefs into it still needed to be valid, so I paid to copy each buffer substring into an internment area (an `unordered_set<string>`), and have the memref point there instead.  Then I discovered it was difficult and inconvenient to find a spot in the process when the internment area could be cleared all at once (to prevent its growing without bound), and I began trying to redesign the internment area so that when all memrefs to an interned string were gone, the string would be removed from the pool.  Hence the shared_ptr.

As I mentioned in my comment to @Peter R, I was even less comfortable with move semantics and containers and references than I am now, and it's quite possible I didn't code my simple, string-based solution to use all that C++11 can offer.  By now I seem to have been traveling in a great circle.

Answer (score 1):

The unordered_set owns the strings. When it goes out of scope your strings will be freed.
My first impression is that your approach does not sound like it will result in a positive experience with respect to maintainability or testability. Certainly this

```
shared_ptr<string> a = &(*string_pool.emplace("foo").first);
```

is wrong. You already have an owner for the string in your unordered_set. Trying to put another ownership layer on it with the shared_ptr is not going to work. You could have an `unordered_set<shared_ptr<string>>` but even that I would not recommend.

Without understanding the rest of your code base it's hard to recommend a 'solution' here. The combination of move semantics and passing `const string&` should handle most requirements at a low level. If there are still performance issues they may then be architectural. Certainly using only `shared_ptr<string>` may solve your life-time issues if there is no natural owner of the string, and they are cheap to copy, just don't use the `unordered_set<string>` in that case.

Comment: The unordered_set will never go out of scope.  I guess its main contribution is to keep only a single instance of each string value.  However, more to the point, when I originally wrote the code I've been trying to optimize, I understood a lot less about move semantics and references than I do now, and I suspect I wrote it inefficiently.  I will append to the OQ a better explanation of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: An object called a "Block" has an input buffer into which is read tab-separated character strings. Block's buffer parser creates a `vector` of `std::strings`.  The user calls Block accessor methods to obtain these strings.  Once they are in the user's hands, their lifetime is unpredictable, and they can certainly outlive the input buffer and the vector of strings.  Would you agree that there is no "natural owner" of such a string?

Answer (score 1):

You've gone a bit wayward.  `shared_ptr`s conceptually form a set of shared owners of an object... the first `shared_ptr` should be created with `make_shared`, then the other copies are created automatically (with "value" semantics) when that value is copied.  What you're attempting to do is flawed in that:

- the `string_pool` itself stores `string`s that don't partake in the shared ownership, nor is there any way in which the `string_pool` is notified or updated when the `shared_ptr`'s reference count hits 0
- the `share_ptr`s have no relationship to each other (you're giving both of them raw pointers rather than copying one to make the other)

For your usage, you need to decide whether you'll pro-actively `erase` the string from the `string_pool` at some point in time, otherwise you may want to put a `weak_ptr` in the `string_pool` and check whether the shared `string` actually still exists before using it.  You can google weak_ptr if you're not already familiar with the concept.

---

Separately, it's worth checking whether your current observation that string copying is a performance problem is due to inefficient coding.  For example:

- are your `string` variables passed around by reference where possible, e.g.:`const std::string&` function parameters whenever you won't change them
- do you use `static const string`s rather than continual run-time recreation from string literals/character arrays?
- are you compiling with a sensible level of optimisation (e.g. -O2, /O2)
- are there places where a keeping a reference to a `string`, and offsets within the string would massively improve performance and reduce memory usage (the referenced string must be kept around as long as it's used even indirectly) - it is very common to implement a "`string_ref`" or similar class for this is medium- and larger-sized C++ projects

Comment: As a matter of fact, this *was* a "memref" that pointed into an input buffer.  Then I discovered circumstances when the buffer needed to be used a second time while memrefs into the first buffer still needed to be valid, so I "interned" every substring as a separate string in an `unordered_set<string>` first, and then pointed the memref there.  I assumed that there would always be a point at which the user could call a function to clear the interned set, but this wasn't always easy.  So I decided to try strings that would go away when no longer referenced.

Comment: (See UPDATE 1 of original question for a fuller explanation)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how to use shared_ptr.  It sounds like my biggest flaw was in thinking that the removal of the final reference to a string could somehow cause the string to be erased from the unordered_set.

Comment: @Chap: I've read over your update.  My suggestion: work out a length profile for your strings... if they're typically short (e.g. up to say 32 characters), you'll want to check your Standard Library implementation for a Short String Optimisation (my guess is that they'd probably only support 8-16 anyway) - if it lacks SSO you could download a string implementation that implements it.  If SSO suits, no need for `shared_ptr`.  Otherwise, with `share_ptr` forget "interning": just let the copies "float" around in their places of actual use then disappear when use stops; no `set` needed.